# how to categorize sql inputs according to models in django

Tags: python, django

I want to learn django and I should categorize my sql inputs according to my models.

For example I have some models like this:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    authorName = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.authorName


class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Authors, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bookName = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    downloadLink = models.FileField()
    downloadCount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bookName
```

and I want to an output in my .html file like this;

---

**Sherlock Holmes**

- A Study in Scarlet
- The Sign of the Four
- The Hound of the Baskervilles

**Suzanne Collins**

- The Hunger Games
- Catching Fire
- Mockingjay

---

I tried this code in my html file but it doesn't work

```
<ul>
  {% for author in all_authors %}

      <h2>{{ author.authorName }}</h2>

      {% for book in all_books %}
          {% if book.author == author.authorName %}

              <li><a href="{{ book.downloadLink.url }}" download="{{ book.downloadLink.url }}">{{ book.bookName }}</a></li>

          {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

My output is;

---

**Sherlock Holmes**

**Suzanne Collins**

---

Here is my view.py file;

```
def books(request):
    return render(request,'../templates/library/library-template.html', {
        'all_authors': Author.objects.all(),
        'all_books': Book.objects.all(),
    })
```

How can I fix it? Or are there any different solution for fix this?

Thank you.. :)

Comment: Define "it doesn't work", what is the exact issue and what have you tried?

Comment: my input is contains only <h2> tags. I'm editting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement will never be true, you are comparing an object and a string

```
      {% if book.author == author.authorName %}
```

So you could change this to

```
      {% if book.author == author %}
```

But this is still wasteful, you can just use the [reverse lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) so you won't need the if statement at all

```
<ul>
  {% for author in all_authors %}

      <h2>{{ author.authorName }}</h2>

      {% for book in author.book_set.all %}

              <li><a href="{{ book.downloadLink.url }}" download="{{ book.downloadLink.url }}">{{ book.bookName }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}

  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```